Why is there a line going through a part of the circle?
I am making a collision system but the intersections of a partial circle are not working. There is a line that is going through the edge of the circle can anyone help? I am using canvas as well.
This is so you can see the output


let world = {}
let cnvs, ctx, cnvs2, ctx2, cnvs3, ctx3;
let n;

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  // Calculating distance 
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) +
    Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) * 1.0);
}

function mod(x, y) {
  let output = x;
  while (output >= y) {
    output -= y
  }
  return output
}

function intersecting(n, t, r, e) {
  return intersect(n.x, n.y, t.x, t.y, r.x, r.y, e.x, e.y)
}

function intersect(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {

  // Check if none of the lines are of length 0
  if ((x1 === x2 && y1 === y2) || (x3 === x4 && y3 === y4)) {
    return false
  }

  denominator = ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))

  // Lines are parallel
  if (denominator === 0) {
    return false
  }

  let ua = ((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / denominator
  let ub = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3)) / denominator

  // is the intersection along the segments
  if (ua < 0 || ua > 1 || ub < 0 || ub > 1) {
    return false
  }

  // Return a object with the x and y coordinates of the intersection
  let x = x1 + ua * (x2 - x1)
  let y = y1 + ua * (y2 - y1)

  return {
    x,
    y
  }
}

function inteceptCircleLineSeg(circle, line, check2, noN) {
  if (!n) n = 0
  var a, b, c, d, u1, u2, ret, retP1, retP2, v1, v2;
  v1 = {};
  v2 = {};
  v1.x = line.x2 - line.x;
  v1.y = line.y2 - line.y;
  v2.x = line.x - circle.x;
  v2.y = line.y - circle.y;
  b = (v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y);
  c = 2 * (v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y);
  b *= -2;
  d = Math.sqrt(b * b - 2 * c * (v2.x * v2.x + v2.y * v2.y - circle.radius * circle.radius));

  if (isNaN(d)) { // no intercept
    return false;
  }
  u1 = (b - d) / c; // these represent the unit distance of point one and two on the line
  u2 = (b + d) / c;
  retP1 = {}; // return points
  retP2 = {}
  ret = []; // return array
  if (u1 <= 1 && u1 >= 0) { // add point if on the line segment
    retP1.x = line.x + v1.x * u1;
    retP1.y = line.y + v1.y * u1;
    ret[0] = retP1;
  } else {
    //if (!check2) world.drawBackup.push({type:'arc',x:line.x + v1.x * u1,y:line.y + v1.y * u1,radius:5,start:0,end:2*Math.PI,lineWidth:1})
  }
  if (u2 <= 1 && u2 >= 0) { // second add point if on the line segment
    retP2.x = line.x + v1.x * u2;
    retP2.y = line.y + v1.y * u2;
    ret[ret.length] = retP2;
  } else {
    //if (!check2) world.drawBackup.push({type:'arc',x:line.x + v1.x * u2,y:line.y + v1.y * u2,radius:15,start:0,end:2*Math.PI,lineWidth:1})
  }
  if (ret.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!check2) {
    if (mod(circle.end, 2 * Math.PI) !== circle.start) {
      let partial = false;
      for (let i = circle.end; i < circle.end + circle.start; i += 0.01) {
        if (u1 <= 1 && u1 >= 0) {
          if (inteceptCircleLineSeg({
              radius: 1,
              x: Math.cos(i) * circle.radius + circle.x,
              y: Math.sin(i) * circle.radius + circle.y,
              start: 0,
              end: Math.PI
            }, {
              x: line.x,
              y: line.y,
              x2: retP1.x,
              y2: retP1.y
            }, true)) {
            ret[0].x = line.x + v1.x * u2
            ret[0].y = line.y + v1.y * u2
            partial = true
            let intersection = intersecting({
              x: Math.cos(circle.end) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.x,
              y: Math.sin(circle.end) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.y
            }, {
              x: Math.cos(circle.start) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.x,
              y: Math.sin(circle.start) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.y
            }, {
              x: line.x,
              y: line.y
            }, {
              x: ret[0].x,
              y: ret[0].y
            })
            if (!intersection) {
              return false
            }
          }
        } else if (u2 <= 1 && u2 >= 0) {
          if (inteceptCircleLineSeg({
              radius: 1,
              x: Math.cos(i) * circle.radius + circle.x,
              y: Math.sin(i) * circle.radius + circle.y,
              start: 0,
              end: Math.PI
            }, {
              x: line.x,
              y: line.y,
              x2: retP2.x,
              y2: retP2.y
            }, true)) {
            ret[0].x = line.x + v1.x * u1
            ret[0].y = line.y + v1.y * u1
            partial = true
            let intersection = intersecting({
              x: Math.cos(circle.end) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.x,
              y: Math.sin(circle.end) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.y
            }, {
              x: Math.cos(circle.start) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.x,
              y: Math.sin(circle.start) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.y
            }, {
              x: line.x,
              y: line.y
            }, {
              x: ret[0].x,
              y: ret[0].y
            })
            if (!intersection) {
              return false
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (partial) {
        if (circle.fill) {
          let intersection = intersecting({
            x: Math.cos(circle.end) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.x,
            y: Math.sin(circle.end) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.y
          }, {
            x: Math.cos(circle.start) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.x,
            y: Math.sin(circle.start) * (circle.radius + 0.5) + circle.y
          }, {
            x: line.x,
            y: line.y
          }, {
            x: ret[0].x,
            y: ret[0].y
          })
          if (intersection) {
            ret[0].x = intersection.x
            ret[0].y = intersection.y
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
world.mouseX = 0;
world.mouseY = 0;

function addEvent(el, ev, func) {
  el.addEventListener(ev, func, false)
}

function removeEvent(el, ev, func) {
  el.removeEventListener(ev, func)
}
world.cubeList = [];
world.cubeNum = 0;
world.drawBackup = [];

world.GetMouseCoords = function(e) {
  var posx = 0;
  var posy = 0;
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
    posx = e.pageX;
    posy = e.pageY;
  } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
    posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }

  world.mouseX = posx * cnvs.width / document.documentElement.clientWidth
  world.mouseY = posy * cnvs.height / document.documentElement.clientHeight
}
world.cube = function(x, y, z, texture) {
  this.id = world.cubeNum;
  this.x = cnvs.width / 2 + (x)
  this.y = cnvs.height / 2 + (y)
  this.texture = texture;
  world.cubeList[world.cubeNum] = this;
  world.cubeNum++
}
world.drawList = []
world.drawLength = 0;
world.setupDraw = function(info) {
  ctx.lineWidth = info.lineWidth
  if (info.type !== 'group') ctx.beginPath()
  if (info.type === 'arc') {
    ctx.arc(info.x, info.y, info.radius, info.start, info.end)
    this.start = info.start;
    this.end = info.end;
    this.x = info.x;
    this.y = info.y;
    this.radius = info.radius;
  } else if (info.type === 'line') {
    ctx.moveTo(info.x, info.y)
    ctx.lineTo(info.x2, info.y2)
    this.x = info.x;
    this.y = info.y;
    this.x2 = info.x2;
    this.y2 = info.y2;
  } else if (info.type === 'group') {
    let lineMoveTo = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < info.items.length; i++) {
      let me = info.items[i];
      if (lineMoveTo === 1) ctx.beginPath();
      if (me.type === 'line') {
        if (lineMoveTo === 1) {
          ctx.moveTo(me.x, me.y)
        } else {
          ctx.lineTo(me.x, me.y)
        }
      } else if (me.type === 'arc') {
        ctx.arc(me.x, me.y, me.radius, me.start, me.end)
      } else if (me.type === 'closePath') {
        ctx.closePath()
        lineMoveTo = 1;
      }
      if (me.type !== 'closePath') lineMoveTo = 0;
    }
    this.items = info.items
  }
  if (info.type === 'arc') {
    this.fill = info.fill
    if (info.fill) ctx.fill()
  }
  ctx.stroke()
  this.lineWidth = info.lineWidth;
  this.id = world.drawLength;
  this.type = info.type;
  world.drawList[world.drawLength] = this;
  world.drawLength++
}
world.drawCam = function(cam) {
  n = 0
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  let xList = [];
  let yList = [];
  for (let i = cam.i; i < cam.i + 1; i += 0.01) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cam.x, cam.y);
    let raduis = 600;
    let x = cam.x + Math.cos(i) * raduis
    let y = cnvs.height / 2 + Math.sin(i) * raduis
    let t = inteceptCircleLineSeg({
      radius: 1,
      x: world.mouseX,
      y: world.mouseY,
      start: 0,
      end: Math.PI * 2,
      fill: false
    }, {
      x: cam.x,
      y: cam.y,
      x2: x,
      y2: y
    }, true)
    if (t) ctx.lineWidth = 4
    for (let i2 = 0; i2 < world.drawList.length; i2++) {
      let me = world.drawList[i2];
      if (me.type === 'arc') {
        let touching;
        touching = inteceptCircleLineSeg({
          radius: me.radius,
          x: me.x,
          y: me.y,
          start: me.start,
          end: me.end,
          fill: me.fill
        }, {
          x: cam.x,
          y: cam.y,
          x2: x,
          y2: y
        })
        if (touching) {
          x = touching[0].x;
          y = touching[0].y;
        }
      } else if (me.type === 'line') {
        let touching;
        touching = intersecting({
          x: cam.x,
          y: cam.y
        }, {
          x: x,
          y: y
        }, {
          x: me.x,
          y: me.y
        }, {
          x: me.x2,
          y: me.y2
        })
        if (touching) {
          x = touching.x;
          y = touching.y;
        }
      } else if (me.type === 'group') {
        for (let i3 = 0; i3 < me.items.length; i3++) {
          let me2 = me.items[i3];
          if (me2.type === 'arc') {
            let touching;
            touching = inteceptCircleLineSeg({
              radius: me2.radius,
              x: me2.x,
              y: me2.y,
              start: me2.start,
              end: me2.end,
              fill: false
            }, {
              x: cam.x,
              y: cam.y,
              x2: x,
              y2: y
            })
            if (touching) {
              x = touching[0].x;
              y = touching[0].y;
            }
            if (i3 + 1 < me.items.length) {
              let me3 = me.items[i3 + 1];
              if (me3.type !== 'closePath') {
                let x2 = me3.x;
                let y2 = me3.y;
                if (me3.type === 'arc') {
                  x2 = me3.x + Math.cos(me3.start) * me3.radius;
                  y2 = me3.y + Math.sin(me3.start) * me3.radius;
                }
                touching = intersecting({
                  x: cam.x,
                  y: cam.y
                }, {
                  x: x,
                  y: y
                }, {
                  x: me2.x + me2.radius,
                  y: me2.y
                }, {
                  x: x2,
                  y: y2
                })
                if (touching) {
                  x = touching.x;
                  y = touching.y;
                }
              }
            }
          } else if (me2.type === 'line') {
            if (i3 + 1 < me.items.length) {
              let me3 = me.items[i3 + 1];
              if (me3.type !== 'closePath') {
                let touching;
                let x2 = me3.x;
                let y2 = me3.y;
                if (me3.type === 'arc') {
                  x2 = me3.x + Math.cos(me3.start) * me3.radius;
                  y2 = me3.y + Math.sin(me3.start) * me3.radius;
                }
                touching = intersecting({
                  x: cam.x,
                  y: cam.y
                }, {
                  x: x,
                  y: y
                }, {
                  x: me2.x,
                  y: me2.y
                }, {
                  x: x2,
                  y: y2
                })
                if (touching) {
                  x = touching.x;
                  y = touching.y;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    for (let i2 = 0; i2 < world.drawList.length; i2++) {
      let me = world.drawList[i2];
      if (me.type === 'line') {
        let touching;
        touching = intersecting({
          x: cam.x,
          y: cam.y
        }, {
          x: x,
          y: y
        }, {
          x: me.x,
          y: me.y
        }, {
          x: me.x2,
          y: me.y2
        })
        if (touching) {
          x = touching.x;
          y = touching.y;
        }
      } else if (me.type === 'group') {
        for (let i3 = 0; i3 < me.items.length; i3++) {
          let me2 = me.items[i3];
          if (me2.type === 'arc') {
            if (i3 + 1 < me.items.length) {
              let me3 = me.items[i3 + 1];
              if (me3.type !== 'closePath') {
                let x2 = me3.x;
                let y2 = me3.y;
                if (me3.type === 'arc') {
                  x2 = me3.x + Math.cos(me3.start) * me3.radius;
                  y2 = me3.y + Math.sin(me3.start) * me3.radius;
                }
                touching = intersecting({
                  x: cam.x,
                  y: cam.y
                }, {
                  x: x,
                  y: y
                }, {
                  x: me2.x + me2.radius,
                  y: me2.y
                }, {
                  x: x2,
                  y: y2
                })
                if (touching) {
                  x = touching.x;
                  y = touching.y;
                }
              }
            }
          } else if (me2.type === 'line') {
            if (i3 + 1 < me.items.length) {
              let me3 = me.items[i3 + 1];
              if (me3.type !== 'closePath') {
                let touching;
                let x2 = me3.x;
                let y2 = me3.y;
                if (me3.type === 'arc') {
                  x2 = me3.x + Math.cos(me3.start) * (me3.radius);
                  y2 = me3.y + Math.sin(me3.start) * (me3.radius);
                }
                touching = intersecting({
                  x: cam.x,
                  y: cam.y
                }, {
                  x: x,
                  y: y
                }, {
                  x: me2.x,
                  y: me2.y
                }, {
                  x: x2,
                  y: y2
                })
                if (touching) {
                  x = touching.x;
                  y = touching.y;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    xList.push(x)
    yList.push(y)
  }
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.moveTo(xList[0], yList[0])
  for (let i = 1; i < xList.length; i++) {
    ctx2.lineTo(xList[i], yList[i])
  }
  ctx2.stroke();
  while (world.drawBackup.length > 0) {
    world.draw(world.drawBackup[0])
    let drawBackup = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < world.drawBackup.length; i++) {
      drawBackup.push(world.drawBackup[i])
    }
    world.drawBackup = drawBackup;
  }
}
world.cam = {}
world.draw = function(info) {
  ctx.lineWidth = info.lineWidth
  if (info.type !== 'group') ctx.beginPath()
  if (info.type === 'arc') {
    ctx.arc(info.x, info.y, info.radius, info.start, info.end)
  } else if (info.type === 'line') {
    ctx.moveTo(info.x, info.y)
    ctx.lineTo(info.x2, info.y2)
  } else if (info.type === 'group') {
    let lineMoveTo = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < info.items.length; i++) {
      let me = info.items[i];
      if (lineMoveTo === 1) ctx.beginPath();
      if (me.type === 'line') {
        if (lineMoveTo === 1) {
          ctx.moveTo(me.x, me.y)
        } else {
          ctx.lineTo(me.x, me.y)
        }
      } else if (me.type === 'arc') {
        ctx.arc(me.x, me.y, me.radius, me.start, me.end)
      } else if (me.type === 'closePath') {
        ctx.closePath()
        lineMoveTo = 1;
      }
      if (me.type !== 'closePath') lineMoveTo = 0;
    }
  }
  if (info.type === 'arc') {
    if (info.fill) ctx.fill()
  }
  ctx.stroke()
}
world.runDraw = function(i) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height)
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height)
  ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height)
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx2.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx2.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx3.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx3.fillStyle = "blue";
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < world.drawList.length; i2++) {
    world.draw(world.drawList[i2])
  }
  world.drawCam(world.cam)
}

function setup() {
  new world.setupDraw({
    type: 'arc',
    x: cnvs.width / 2,
    y: cnvs.height / 2,
    radius: 500,
    start: 0,
    end: 2 * Math.PI,
    lineWidth: 8,
    fill: false
  })
  new world.setupDraw({
    type: 'line',
    x: cnvs.width / 2 + Math.sin(1) * 500,
    y: cnvs.height / 2 + Math.cos(1) * 500,
    x2: cnvs.width / 2 + Math.sin(5) * 500,
    y2: cnvs.height / 2 + Math.cos(5) * 500,
    lineWidth: 8
  })
  new world.setupDraw({
    type: 'line',
    x: cnvs.width / 2 + Math.sin(2) * 500,
    y: cnvs.height / 2 + Math.cos(2) * 500,
    x2: cnvs.width / 2 + Math.sin(4) * 500,
    y2: cnvs.height / 2 + Math.cos(4) * 500,
    lineWidth: 8
  })
  new world.setupDraw({
    type: 'group',
    lineWidth: 1,
    items: [{
      type: 'line',
      x: cnvs.width / 2 - 200,
      y: 0
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      x: cnvs.width / 2 - 200,
      y: cnvs.height
    }, {
      type: 'arc',
      x: cnvs.width / 2 - 200,
      y: cnvs.height / 2 - 200,
      radius: 50,
      start: 5,
      end: 2 * Math.PI
    }]
  })
  addEvent(cnvs, 'mousemove', function(e) {
    world.GetMouseCoords(e)
    //$('#output').text(world.mouseX)
  })
  addEvent(cnvs, 'mousedown', function(e) {
    world.GetMouseCoords(e)
    world.cam.x = world.mouseX
    world.cam.y = world.mouseY
  })
  world.cam = {
    i: 4,
    x: (cnvs.width / 2),
    y: (cnvs.height / 2)
  }
  run()
}

function run() {
  world.runDraw(world.cam.i)
  //world.cam.i+=0.01
  setTimeout(() => {
    run()
  }, 1)
}
window.onload = async function() {
  cnvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
  cnvs2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
  cnvs3 = document.getElementById("canvas3");
  cnvs.width = 1000;
  cnvs.height = 1000;
  cnvs.style.background = "black";
  cnvs2.width = 1000;
  cnvs2.height = 1000;
  cnvs2.style.background = "black";
  cnvs3.width = 1000;
  cnvs3.height = 1000;
  cnvs3.style.background = "black";
  ctx = cnvs.getContext('2d')
  ctx2 = cnvs2.getContext('2d')
  ctx3 = cnvs3.getContext('2d')
  setup()
  resize()
  window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
    resize()
  });
}

function resize() {
  let w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  let h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  cnvs.style.position = 'absolute';
  cnvs2.style.position = 'absolute';
  cnvs3.style.position = 'absolute';
  cnvs.style.top = '0px'
  cnvs.style.left = '0px'
  cnvs2.style.top = h + 'px'
  cnvs2.style.left = '0px'
  cnvs3.style.top = (h * 2) + 'px'
  cnvs3.style.left = '0px'
  cnvs.style.width = w + "px";
  cnvs.style.height = h + "px";
  cnvs2.style.width = w + "px";
  cnvs2.style.height = h + "px";
  cnvs3.style.width = w + "px";
  cnvs3.style.height = h + "px";
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
<p id="output" style="position:absolute;top:700px;color:white;"></p>



